# How to aggregate data integer in most efficient way?

Tags: c#, aggregate, calculator, aggregation, mathematical-optimization

I need to aggregate some array values from APIs in a background processing job in c#. The number of APIs can in theory be infinite but will probably never be more than 10.

The APIs return a simple list with UserID and Value. To use the data in my application I need to sum all values for each distinct UserID.

Example-data from two APIs:

**From API 1:**

```
[1, 240] (Note: The data is organized as [UserID, Value])
[2, 160]
[3, 12568]
[4, 1780]
[...]
```

**From API 2:**

```
[1, 10]
[2, 10]
[3, 10]
[4, 10]
[...]
```

**Desired result:**

```
[1, 250]
[2, 170]
[3, 12578]
[4, 1790]
[...]
```

How do I, in the most efficient way make this one desired list where the values for each UserID has been added to each other?

I've been looking at Matrixes which seems to be a way but I can't figure out how to do add values without also adding the UserIDs to each other?

(I realize it can be solved with some nested loops but I'm looking for a better way);

Note: The UserID's are not sequential.

Comment: By sequential, do you mean sorted? I.e., can a stream be [3,10], [1,13]? Do you want the output to be sorted? Are the UserIds always integers?

Comment: I'm guessing Linq isn't fast enough?  `var results = api1Results.Join(api2Results, api1 => api1.UserId, api2 => api2.UserId, (api1, api2) new { UserId = api1.UserId, Value = api1.Value + api2.Value})`

Comment: @willem There can be "gaps", [1,2,4] where 3 is not in the first result but might be in the second result. Sorting doesn't matter. Yes, always integers.

Comment: Are UserIds always that small? How many users are you expecting to have? With a few users and such small ids you can use idea from bucket sort.

Comment: @Smudge202 For to lists it probably is, but is it still if using 10? I have a feeling it must be some better way.

Comment: @PiotrAuguscik They're actually a bit longer, I just used it to make simple example. It's always integers though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Dictionary<int,int>` will probably be faster than anything you can cook up in any other way, even with lookup of whether UserId is already contained as key.

ie:

```
var results = Dictionary<int,int>();
foreach (var api in apis)
    foreach(var value in api.GetValues())
        if (!result.HasKey(value.UserID))
            result[value.UserId] = value.Value;
        else
            result[value.UserId] += value.Value;
```

Comment: A dictionary is certainly the best solution, except if the IDs are a series of integer numbers with almost no gaps. In the latter case I suggest using a List and ignoring unused values.
Instead of using result.HasKey() and result[], result.TryGetValue() should be used in the code given above to halve the number of look-up operations.